How to configure dialogflow cx chatbot to send welcome message without waiting for user input?
i tried building a dialogflow cx chatbot and integrated with dialogflow messenger, and want my bot to initiate the conversation, but it does not start the conversation until there is an input from user.
i have tried multiple things like updating the welcome event in the HTML script and hosting the webpage, also tried creating a welcome page and added the fulfillment in the agent response and enabled the agent, but no luck the chatbot still needs to be triggered by the user utterance.

Are you using Dialogflow CX or ES? What frontend are you using? Dialogflow messenger? You can use a custom event and then trigger that at the start from e.g. Dialogflow Messenger.

i am using dialogflow cx, i tried creating the custom welcome event and tested the agent through console but the welcome message is not triggered.

In the Dialogflow CX Simulator (Test Agent) you can trigger the custom event by clicking on the small + icon right to the input text field. For Dialogflow Messenger you have to set the welcome event as "intent" on the df-messenger element. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger/html#html_customizations_for_df-messenger

thanks, it worked but i am looking for automatic initialization instead on clicking on the input text field and selecting the custom event. will it work on integrated dialogflow messenger when hosted on the website?

Yes, for Dialogflow Messenger it works automatically when Dialogflow messenger has loaded.
